# calculate time complexity of two functions

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory, space-complexity

What is the difference between time complexity of O(n) and O(Log n). Let's say I have a function which has time complexity of O(Log n) and space complexity of n.

What will be the time complexity if I have to calculate addition of two functions with time complexities of:

- Log n and Log n
- Log n and n
- n and n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Take the highest "power" of n

- Log n and Log n -> Log n
- Log n and n -> n
- n and n -> n

Don't bother with the constant term. We are only interested in scaling behaviours, i.e.

> What happens to the overall space or time, when we have n times more?

If the space or time required goes up by *the same* factor, it is O(n).

If it goes upby a constant *additive* step for every scale factor of input size, we say it is O(log N). For example, for sizes of 1, 10, 100, the times may be 4 sec, 4.5 sec, 5 sec. Then you are adding 0.5 seconds for every 10-fold increase in data.

If it goes up by the square of that factor, it is O(n^2).

#### It is not exactly like calculating logarithms

You raise an excellent question:

> Will it not be Log n * Log n -> log^2(n) = log(n)×log(n) = log(n)^2?
>
> I am looking at this answer quora.com/Difference-between-log-2-n-log-log-n-and-log-n-2 qr.ae/pr3wPd

That is the wrong arithmetic.

You were asking about a process that involved *two* subprocesses that have to happen one-after-another. So the time taken is the addition, not the multiplication.

What you want to calculate is

```
log N + log N =  2 log N
```

But for O notation, we disregard the `2`, and just write the result as O(log N).

#### When you have one loop calling another, you multiply the things in the `O()`

As pointed out by @Support Ukraine in the comments:

If an algorithm which is O(log n) calls (in its innermost loop) another algorithm which is *also* O(log n), then the resulting complexity is O((log n) ^2).

#### When you have two additive steps (i.e. not multiplicative), you take the highest "power" of n

If your process involves doing an O(N) thing, and then once that has finished, doing an O(log N) thing, then the overall result is O(N).

This is because once N gets large, the N will grow much faster than log N.

#### Quick summary: think of it as "proportional to"

When you say something is proportional to something else, you don't really care about any constant terms.

Suppose the amount people eat is proportional to their weight. You can say that, without specifying how many meals, days, or years we are talking about. The duration will affect the constant of proportionality but not the concept that "cost of food eaten" is proportional to "body weight".

For example, if you switch between currencies, or add taxes, the constant of proportionality changes, but the proportionality remains.

Comment: Will it not be Log n * Log n -> log^2(n) = log(n)×log(n) = log(n)^2 . I am looking at this answer https://www.quora.com/Difference-between-log-2-n-log-log-n-and-log-n-2  https://qr.ae/pr3wPd

Comment: what do you mean by constant additive step in this context?

Comment: second, is there anything more than O(Log N) in time complexity in O computation? Can I really have a O(Log ^2 n) in O computation? I really got confused here

Comment: Yes! O(N) is worse!O(N^2) is _much_ worse.

Comment: Is it logical computation to have O(Log^2(n)) in O computation? What is worse O(Log n) or O(Log^2(n))

Comment: If an algorithm which is O(log n) calls (in it's inner most loop) another algorithm which is also O(log n) the the resulting complexity is O((log n) ^2)

Comment: thank you. i appreciate. i was getting confused on how the O computations of logs were happening here. god bless.

Comment: @Gary You ask what is worse... O(log n) or O(log^2 n). Try to solve `log^2 n > log n`. As a hint it's just like solving U^2 > U .....

Comment: if i have O(log N) and O(N), the second included in the inner most loop what is the computation -> O(N Log N)

Comment: @Gary Correct.... If one function is called in the inner most loop of another function, you multiply their complexity. If you first call one function and afterwards call another function, you take the worst of the two functions

Comment: thank you. i have a better understanding now.

Comment: @ProfDFrancis +1 to both of you

Comment: @SupportUkraine +1 to both of you